# React.js:How to send Fontawsome icon as props?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I using this object as React.js component props. but after sent it, FontAwsome could not find passed icon

```
 {
      key: 'editButton',
      title: 'Edit',
      icon: 'faEdit',
      function: null,
      type: 'default ',
    },
    {
      key: 'deleteButton',
      title: 'Delete',
      icon: 'faTrash',
      type: 'danger',
      function: null,
    },
```

my component:

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={item.icon} />
```

error:

```
index.js:1 Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName: "faEdit"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass it as a string value, then you'll need to pre-register them first:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/methods/library-add

See this also: [Import all icons from Fontawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882118/import-all-icons-from-fontawesome)

Otherwise, you can explicitly pass them:

```
import { faEdit } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

...
 {
     key: 'editButton',
     title: 'Edit',
     icon: faEdit,
     function: null,
     type: 'default ',
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by a simple condition.
calling components here using

```
<componentName theIcon="faCrown" />
```

and while rendering **componentName** , i used

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.theIcon=== "faCrown" ? faCrown: faLink} />
```

You need to import those icons as well

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how I passed an icon as prop in a custom input**

```
// custom Input with Tailwind Css and formik
import { FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa';

// inside Input component  

<label 
     htmlFor={name} 
     className='block 
     text-sm font-medium 
     text-gray-900 
     dark:text-white'>
 Full Name
</label>

<div className='relative'>
   {icon && (
            <div className='flex 
                   absolute inset-y-0 
                   left-0 pl-3 items-center 
                   pointer-events-none'>
               {icon} // <== displaying the passed icon into Input
            </div>
  )}
  <input type='text' {...field} {...props} /> //<-- formik
</div>

// You call it where you want it as follow
<Input 
      type='text'
      name='name'
      label='Full Name'
      // Passing icon below as prop
      icon={<FaUser className={iconCls} fill='currentColor' />} 
/>
```

**Result**
[image]